# Does LinkedIn SlideShare support audio?

Tags: slideshare

It looks like you used to be able to add audio to slideshare presentations:

1. http://www.slideshare.net/cmkraut/creating-narrated-presentations-with-slideshare-narrated
2. http://www.slideshare.net/msincome/adding-audio-to-slideshare

I don't seem to be able to find those same settings any more. Is still possible?

(I would like to make it a "narrated" presentation)